# How do I move a row of a table in DOORS?

Tags: row, ibm-doors

## Problem

I have data in one row of a DOORs table that I need to move to another location in a table. I know of [shift-clicking](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYQBZ_9.6.1/com.ibm.doors.requirements.doc/topics/c_draganddropobjects.html), but all this does is move the whole table:

> You can copy or move tables within a module or between modules using drag-and-drop. To copy or move a table using drag-and-drop, click any cell in the table. The whole table is moved when you drag-and-drop the table cell.

## Question

Other than the following 2 methods:

1. Copy-pasting the data between the row I want to move from and the row I want to move to.
2. Undoing my actions and recreating the row where I want it.

Is there a way in DOORs to move a row to a different location in the same table of origin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to say 'no'.

Without the ability to run a DXL script, I don't think there is a way in DOORS to do what you are asking.

Sorry.